# Error:(9, 30) error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm using Studio 0.8.9
I have an android-sdks\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar
but I still run into the import issue.
I'm using NavUtils.navigateupfromsametask method.
what I'm trying to achieve is simply to use the back button to get to my previous activity.

is it the right way of doing?
when I'm using my email app (for ex yahoo) I'm using the back button to get back to my inbox when I'm viewing an email.

how do they do it? using activities and the back button?

---

I'm using the standard code:

```
package com.example.bernard.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.NavigableMap;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class Statistic extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistic);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.statistic, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id)
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need `NavUtils`? Just calling the onBackPressed() should work. You could also call `finish()` and it would close the current activity and bring you back to the previous one.

Comment: it takes me to my home (or current view in android) view. when i click on the apps running and i click on my app it is back in the previous activity.

Comment: many thanks that you have trigerred the right thing to do. in fact i had a finish() aftr the stractivity. it works like a charm :)